# Указать данные авторизации прокси

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

При сборке проекта на IntelliJ IDEA получаю такую ошибку

> Could not GET
>   'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/2.1.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-2.1.6.RELEASE.pom'.
>   Received status code 407 from server: **Proxy Authentication Required**
>   Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

Где можно указать данные для авторизации на прокси сервере?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> HTTP Proxy**

Далее выбираем Manual proxy configuration и ставим галочку Proxy Authentication

[image: Настройки]